# Async lambda expression converted to a 'Task' returning delegate cannot return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I have the following in an ASP.NET Core application (`Startup.cs`, `Configure` method):

I just added the `async` keyword, because I needed the `await` one... 
So now, I am getting the following:

> Error CS8031  Async lambda expression converted to a '`Task`' returning
>   delegate cannot return a value. Did you intend to return '`Task<T>`'?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ITableRepositories repository)
{
    // ...  
    app.UseStaticFiles();    
    app.UseCookieAuthentication();

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
    {
        ClientId = Configuration["..."],
        Authority = Configuration["..."],
        CallbackPath = Configuration["..."],
        Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context => { return Task.FromResult(0); },
            OnRemoteSignOut = context => { return Task.FromResult(0); },
            OnTicketReceived = async context =>
            {
                var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Ticket.Principal.Identity;
                if (user.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var firstName = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;
                    // ...
                    List<Connection> myList = new List<Connection>() { c };
                    var results = await repository.InsertOrMergeAsync(myList);
                    var myConnection = (results.First().Result as Connection);                         
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0); // <<< ERROR HERE ....... !!!
            },
            OnTokenValidated = context => { return Task.FromResult(0); },
            OnUserInformationReceived = context => { return Task.FromResult(0); },
        }
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>        { ...        });
}
```

[image]

What should I return in that case? I tried to `return 0;`, but the error message doesn't change...

PS. The `OnTicketRecieved` signature

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
{
    public class RemoteAuthenticationEvents : IRemoteAuthenticationEvents
    {
        public Func<TicketReceivedContext, Task> OnTicketReceived { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please DO NOT delete your question because it was closed and recreate a new identical question to get rid of the close votes and the comments. – Also, I was just about to answer your original question actually when you deleted it…

Comment: What delegate type is `OnTicketReceived` expecting?

Comment: @MikeStrobel I updated the OP to explain it

Comment: It sounds like `OnTicketReceived` wants a delegate that returns a `Task`, i.e., a task with no result.  I'd guess when you added `async`, your lambda's implicit return type became `async Task`.  That means you can't return a value, so treat your lambda as if it's returning `void`.  Just remove your return statement entirely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message is actually self-explanatory:

> Async lambda expression converted to a `'Task'` returning delegate cannot return a value. Did you intend to return `'Task<T>'`?

So you have an async lambda expression which is supposed to return a `Task`—not a `Task<T>` for any `T`.

But when you do `return 0` you are returning an int, so the return type of your async method is `Task<int>`, not `Task`. What the compiler wants you to do there is to return *no value at all*.

```
OnTicketReceived = async context =>
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Because of the SO editor the `Task<T>` text transformed in Task, so my quote were wrong. Fixed. And please don't donvote me and ask for code if you don't need it

Comment: So how do you return results in this case>?  Such as a http status code and message?

Comment: @DanielWilliams The event handlers are supposed to interact with the passed `context` if they want to control the authentication flow. If you want to terminate the HTTP request, you can write directly to the response of the HttpContext, though I would recommend doing that inside your authentication events since that will very likely interrupt the authentication process in a non-recoverable manner.